# Excel utf8 encoding (BOM is not working)

Tags: php

I just want to export data in the csv format and open it in excel. This method writes one row into it.

```
    public function writeRow(array $row)
    {
        $str = $this->rowToStr($row);
        $encodedStr = mb_convert_encoding($str, 'UTF-16LE', 'UTF-8');
        $ret = fwrite($this->_getFilePointer('w+'), $encodedStr);

        /* According to http://php.net/fwrite the fwrite() function
         should return false on error. However not writing the full 
         string (which may occur e.g. when disk is full) is not considered 
         as an error. Therefore both conditions are necessary. */
        if (($ret === false) || (($ret === 0) && (strlen($str) > 0)))  {
                throw new Exception("Cannot open file $this",
                Exception::WRITE_ERROR, NULL, 'writeError');
        }
    }
```

Then i will try to write a row.

```
$csvFile->writeRow(array(chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF)));
$csvHeaders = array('ID', 'Email', 'Variabilní symbol', 'Jméno', 'Příjmení',
'Stav', 'Zaregistrován', 'Zaregistrován do');
$csvFile->writeRow($csvHeaders);
```

And the result is :

ID,"Email","Variabilní symbol","Jméno","PYíjmení","Stav","Zaregistrován","Zaregistrován do"

Only a few letters are not correct (the method mb_convert_encoding does the trick)

I have tried the traditional way

```
// Open file pointer to standard output
    $fp = fopen($filePath, 'w');

    // Add BOM to fix UTF-8 in Excel
    fputs($fp, $bom = (chr(0xEF) . chr(0xBB) . chr(0xBF)));
    fclose($fp)
```

And the result was the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BOM you've mentioned is for UTF-8, but your data is UTF-16LE. Therefore you should use a different BOM:

```
$bom = chr(0xFF) . chr(0xFE)
```

Or in your code:

```
$fp = fopen($filePath, 'w');
fputs($fp, chr(0xFF) . chr(0xFE));

// Add lines here...

fclose($fp);
```